# Side menu not opening on the page opened via button on modal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an ionic app with a side menu.

In my app, i added a modal that contains three button. When i click on any button in that modal, it opens a new page. On that new page, i have header containing a button that is used to open the side menu.

**Problem**

Side menu opens normally on any page that isn't opened via buttons on modal but when i try to open the side menu on a page that was opened via button on a modal, instead of opening the side menu on that page, it opens the side menu behind the current page and when i press back button to go back to previous page, side menu can be seen opened on the previous page.

**Question**

What is causing this behavior and how can i fix it ?

**Custom Modal typescript code**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LibraryPageSerice } from './libraryPage.service';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-custom-posting-pop-up',
  templateUrl: 'custom-posting-pop-up.html',
})
export class CustomPostingPopUpPage {

  onLibraryPage: boolean;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams,
              private viewCtrl: ViewController,
              private libService: LibraryPageSerice) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.onLibraryPage = this.libService.onLibraryPage;
  }

  dismissModal(event) {
    if(event.target.className === 'modal-container') {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
  }

  openCreationpage() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    this.navCtrl.push('PostingCreationPage');
  }

  openSupportivePage() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    this.navCtrl.push('PostingSupportivePage');
  }

  openLibraryPage() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    this.navCtrl.push('MylibraryPage');
  }
}
```

**Custom modal html code**

```
<div class="modal-container" (click)="dismissModal($event)">

  <div class="modal">
    <p>Posting Method</p>

    <div class="btn-container">
      <button class="creation-btn" (click)="openCreationpage()">My Creation</button>
      <button class="supportive-btn" (click)="openSupportivePage()">Supportive</button>
      <button *ngIf="!onLibraryPage" class="library-btn" (click)="openLibraryPage()">
        My Library
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This method is used to open the modal

```
posting() {
    const modal = this.modalCtrl.create('CustomPostingPopUpPage');
    modal.present();
}
```

If i don't use the modal and instead use an alert dialog to open the new page, side menu opens normally. So this problem only arises when i use a modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of how modals are defined to work, ["A Modal is a content pane that goes over the user's current page ... A modal uses the NavController to present itself in the root nav stack"](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/)
Because of this when you are calling this.navCtrl.push('PageName'); this instance of NavController is an Overlay Portal whereas a normal NavController not from a modal is a Nav. This will cause the page to be pushed along side your app-root (Which causes the results that you are witnessing).

Here are two solutions to this.

Pass in reference of NavController to your modal using NavParams

```
// home.ts
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create('ModalPage', {'nav': this.navCtrl});

// modal.ts
nav: Nav;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          public navParams: NavParams,
          public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
this.nav = this.navParams.get('nav');
}
openSupportivePage() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    this.nav.push('PostingSupportivePage');
}
```

Or pass which page you want to open to viewCtrl.dismiss() and parse with onDidDismiss

```
// home.ts
modal.onDidDismiss((open_page) => {
  if (open_page !== undefined && open_page.hasOwnProperty('open_page')) {
    this.navCtrl.push(open_page['open_page']);
  }
});

// modal.ts
openCreationpage() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss({'open_page': 'PostingCreationPage'});
}
```